# Evaluating $\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x^3+a}{p}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

We know that

$$\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x^2+a}{p}\right) = -1$$

for any $p\ge 3$, $p\nmid a$.

Is there any way to evaluate the following?

$$\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x^{\mathbf{3}} + a}{p}\right)$$

Some empirical computation shows that the value fluctuates a bit, so I'm not sure if there's a pattern.

Comment: You can find expressions for both sums in terms of $a,p$. You could solve a polynomial equation (I believe it's a quadratic) to find $p$ in terms of $a$. And then plug this value into the second sum.

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify what you mean? I know how to compute the sum for $x^2+a$ but it involves rewriting the sum into $\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x+a}{p}\right)\left(\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)+1\right)$, so I'm not sure how to apply that here.

Comment: For an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$ the number of points does not have a closed form but obeys the Hasse-Weil bound: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/hasse-weil-bound/

Comment: Hasse-Weil bound says that the sum has absolute value at most $2\sqrt p$. I don't think much more can be said.